# Unable to select JS dropdown option in python selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

My HTML view-
[Wesite view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKKZT.png)

HTML code- [HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBv3b.png)

Following code come into view only when i click dropdown arrow-
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzaWq.png) 
My code can show the dropdown options but can not select an option from it-

```
drop1 = driver.find_element_byxpath("//*[@id='s2id_autogen1']/a/span[2]")
drop1.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// click on the `Administrative Owner` to trigger the dropdown display out
driver.find_element_by_xxx('yyy').click()

optionText = 'aapt-midrangewindows'
xpath = "//div[@id='select2-drop']/ul/li[.='{1}']".format(optionText)

// choose the option by given option text
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already find another way to get it working.